Configuring Spring Boot application to run a Web Interface on HTTPS and Web Services on HTTP
I’m new to Spring Boot, and might not have the grasp on all of spring basis.
My application serves a set of webservices and have a web interface to display some of the data.
I’m facing an issue with configuring my application to run both the web interface and web services with different protocols(http/https).
This is needed since the web service clients only can run as http(they will be updated in the future).
Here’s my setup:
Web Interface (UI) is currently running at endpoint – localhost:port/web/**
Web Services (API) is currently running at endpoint – localhost:port/ws/**
Currently my application work if the full application(both web interface and webservices) runs as http.
My application endpoints is configured as follows:
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Disable LDAP login for All endpoint web services (/ws/**)
        http
                .requiresChannel(channelConfigurer -> channelConfigurer.anyRequest().requiresInsecure())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/ws/**"))
                        .permitAll());

        // Enforce LDAP login for the web management interface (/web/**)
        http
                .requiresChannel(channelConfigurer -> channelConfigurer.anyRequest().requiresSecure())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/web/**"))
                        .authenticated().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();
    }

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.
To solve the problem I have tried:

Setup the application to use https - but is affected the full application(both web interface and webservices)  and could not get it seperated.

I have try to force https to only the web interface endpoint - localhost:port/web/**
But it did not work.


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain secureSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // Configure the security filter chain for secure (HTTPS) requests.
        return httpSecurity.securityMatcher("/web/**")
                .requiresChannel(channelConfigure ->
                        channelConfigure
                                .requestMatchers(ServletRequest::isSecure)
                                //.requiresInsecure() // Require HTTP
                                //.requiresSecure() // Require HTTPS
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .anyRequest().permitAll() // Allow all secure requests
                )
                .build();
    }

